# Rewrite Javascript path String

Tags: javascript, regex, string

In Javascript, I have a string for a path that looks like:

```
/xxx:Level1/yyy:Level2/xxx:Level3/ccc:Level4
```

The prefix may or may not be there for each level.  I need to create a new string which eliminates the prefix on each folder level, something like:

```
/Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4
```

OK.  I've done something like the following, but I think perhaps with regex it could be made more compact.  How could I do that?

```
var aa = "/xxx:Level1/yyy:Level2/xxx:Level3/ccc:Level4"

var bb = aa.split("/").filter(String);
var reconstructed = "";

for( var index in bb )
{
 var dirNames = bb[index].split(":");
 if(dirNames.length==1) reconstructed += "/" + dirNames[0];
 else if(dirNames.length==2) reconstructed += "/" + dirNames[1];
 }
```

Comment: Wow!  You guys are amazingly fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var bb = aa.replace(/\/[a-z]+:/g, '/');
```

Change the `[a-z]` to include any characters that might appear in the prefix, or just use `[^\/:]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex like this:

```
var str = "/xxx:Level1/yyy:Level2/xxx:Level3/ccc:Level4";
var out = str.replace(/\/[^:\/]+:/g, "/");
alert(out);
```

This matches:

```
/
followed by one or more characters that is not a : or a /
followed by a :
and replaces all that with a / effectively eliminating the xxx:
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hbUkz/

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = "/xxx:Level1/yyy:Level2/xxx:Level3/ccc:Level4";
var b = a.replace(/\/[^\/]*:/g, "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aa = aa.replace(/\/[^:\/]\:/g, "/");
```

This function will replace every occurence of `"/xxx:"` by `"/"` using a RE, where `xxx:` is a prefix.